# Control the scale of a floating point number

Tags: floating-point, common-lisp, precision

Is there a way to control the scale of a floating point number in lisp:

instead of 89.833336 I would like my output to be 89.83

Searched high and low for an appropriate function in the HyperSpec - can't find one.

```
(defun average(&rest nums)
   (float (/ (apply #'+ nums) (length nums))))

(average 99 97 78 88 99 78) --> 89.833336
```

Comment: What is the actual goal or what problem are you trying to solve? Ordinarily you would either do calculations with full precision and "control the scale" in printed representations, or you would implement a fixed-point number type.

Comment: When printing, use the `~,2F` format directive: `(format t "~,2f" 89.833336)`

Answer (score 1):

Output means printing, right?

```lisp
(format t "~,2F" f)
```

(Ehvince commented that already)

You might also want to check if you could work with ratios instead.

Edit: it seems you want to truncate instead of rounding.  You can do that on the numeric side:

```lisp
(defun format-truncated (n p)
  (let ((x (expt 10 (- p))))
    (format nil "~,2f"
            (* (truncate n x) x))))
```

or clip the output:

```lisp
(defun format-clipped (n p)
  (let ((s (format nil "~,vf" (1+ p) n)))
    (subseq s 0 (+ (position #\. s) p 1))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Actually, this rounds up. So for example if I have a float that looks like this: 89.84615, format give me 89.85. I actually came up with a solution - admittedly it's ugly and only addresses a scale of 2.  The reason for all of this is:

Comment: @DavidNRichards: Edit the question to specify the rounding that you want.

Answer (score 0):

From a comment:

> Actually, this rounds up. So for example if I have a float that looks like this: 89.84615, format give me 89.85.

So you want to truncate the number to N places instead? Try this:

```lisp
(defun truncate-after-decimal (num &key (digits 2))
  "Return a string representation of a floating point number with at most
 digits digits after the decimal point, truncating instead of rounding."
  (let* ((str (format nil "~F" num))
         (decimal-pos (position #\. str)))
    ; In cases where there's no decimal point or not enough digits, just
    ; return the entire string. Adjust as desired.
    (if (and decimal-pos (<= (+ decimal-pos digits 1) (length str)))
        (subseq str 0 (+ decimal-pos digits 1))
        str)))

;;; Examples
;;; CL-USER> (truncate-after-decimal 89.833336)
;;; "89.83"
;;; CL-USER> (truncate-after-decimal 89.84615)
;;; "89.84"
```

Instead of doing potentially error-inducing floating point math, first convert the number to a string as is and then return just a prefix of it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you want to do is to control how the number is *printed*, not to actually round it, then you can control how the language prints floats (or anything)

One way to do this is to define `print-object` methods.  The problem with that is that these are global.  Another way to do it which is less global is to control the pretty printer.  Unfortunately the pretty printer interface is kind of horrible I think, but here is how you might do that:

```
(set-pprint-dispatch
 'float
 (let ((fallback (pprint-dispatch 1.0 nil)))
   (lambda (s o)
     (if *print-readably*
         (funcall fallback s o)
       (format s "~,2F" o))))
 0
 *ppd*)
```

And now

```
(defvar *ppd* (copy-pprint-dispatch))

(set-pprint-dispatch
 'float
 (let ((fallback (pprint-dispatch 1.0 nil)))
   (lambda (s o)
     (if *print-readably*
         (funcall fallback s o)
       (format s "~,2F" o))))
 0
 *ppd*)

(setf *print-pretty* t
      *print-readably nil
      *print-pprint-dispatch* *ppd*)
```

So now

```
> 1.2346
1.23

> 1.2356
1.24

> (let ((*print-readably* t))
    (print 1.2346))

1.2346 
1.23
```

Answer (score -1):

You can multiply the float by 100, round it, and then divide it by 100, which will round it to two decimal places.

```lisp
(defun round_to_two (num)
  (/ (float (round (* num 100))) 100))
```

If you just want to trim the extra digits, use `floor` instead of `round`.

Comment: That worked beautifully - thank you!

Comment: Floor/round allows second argument, so * is not needed:  (/ (float (round num .01)) 100)

Comment: And float is not needed if 100 is float:   (/ (round num .01) 100.0)

Comment: This is not a good general solution, as the resulting binary float is not guaranteed to be represented as exactly /n/ digits.

Comment: Multiplying and dividing introduce rounding errors that will make the result incorrect in some cases. If the rounding is for the purposes of output, then rounding to decimal digits ought to be done by using the conversion built into the formatting routines of libraries (assuming they are correctly implemented).